# Does AWS WAF prevent GET flood?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf, amazon-alb

Let's say I have an imaginary website: `https://myimaginarywebsite.com`.

If I try to exploit it, and I make massive concurrent GET requests (source is just one `ip`), would WAF have a feature to prevent this?

Since this is technically valid traffic but abnormal pattern, I'm curious how AWS WAF handles this.

Is there an already built-in WAF feature we can just add to prevent this, or Do we have still have to tune this in WAF?

Comment: This might be a better fit for sister site ServerFault.com since it's server / network setup not coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WAF can handle HTTP floods with rate based rules.

The AWS Security Automations quick start [found here](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/aws-waf-security-automations/), and associated docs [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-waf-security-automations/welcome.html), provide a great template starting point and example of some of the features you can configure in AWS WAF.